# Symfony2 : Retrieve app.request in Twig from a command

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to generate a mail template into a Symfony2 command, everything works except that {{app.request}} is null into Twig (I need it for sheme and httpHost) because it is called from a cli context. I've tried to change that scope with :

```
$this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
$this->getContainer()->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
```

but it's not providing app.request . Is there a solution to fix this ?

Comment: There **isn't** a request, since you're calling it from the command line. A request is built from a HTTP request - a command does not generate a HTTP request. What is it you're trying to get from the request?

Comment: I was excpecting such response... I need it to generate some image src :  <img src="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~  asset( 'public/img/email/logo.png') }}"> And those templates are also used with my controller, I wanted to avoid to create variable to generate that src.

Comment: So, yeah, there is no request, and hence no scheme or host. You could pass in parameters when rendering the template. Or make custom Twig functions that generate the `src` based on a flag from the command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Symfony Guide suggest to configure the Request Context Globally, so you make a static configuration un your parameters and set the Context of the Symfony Router Component programmatically.

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
  router.request_context.host: example.org
  router.request_context.scheme: https
  router.request_context.base_url: my/path


 // src/Acme/DemoBundle/Command/DemoCommand.php

 // ...
class DemoCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
 {
    $context = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext();
    $context->setHost('example.com');
    $context->setScheme('https');
    $context->setBaseUrl('my/path');

    // ... your code here
 }
}
```

[There is a specific paragraph for this problem on the guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html)

Answer (score 5):

In your command:

```
$this->render('template.html.twig', [
    'scheme' => 'https',
    'host' => 'example.com',
]);
```

In your template:

```
{% if app.request is defined %}{{ app.request.scheme }}{% else %}{{ scheme|default('http') }}{% endif %}
```

Personally, I would abstract the img src generation to a function, instead of hardcoding that logic all over the place in templates.